# golang, read contents from file, and send as body data in HTTP request

Tags: http, go, filereader

```
//read data from a file config.json
//the contents of config.json is
//{"key1":"...Z-DAaFpGT0t...","key2":"..."}
 client :=   &http.Client{}
 dat, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/config.json")
 req, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", url, bytes.NewBuffer(dat))
 resp, err := client.Do(req)
```

Then I will get error from server saying "400 Bad Request", " "invalid character 'ï' looking for beginning of value"".

It seems the data is not properly decoded.

While code below works

```
 client :=   &http.Client{}
 //dat, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/config.json")
 var dat = []byte(`{"key1":"...Z-DAaFpGT0t...","key2":"..."}`)
 req, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", url, bytes.NewBuffer(dat))
 resp, err := client.Do(req)
```

Comment: Are you checking those errors?

Comment: Can you share the contents of /config.json?

Answer (score 0):

please check `content-type` your server required, and build the body as `content-type` required.

as your `content-type` is `application/json; charset=utf-8`, you try to set it manully

```
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
```

if it still not work, make a http load capture please.

Comment: what `content-type` your server required?

Comment: application/json; charset=utf-8